# The first electron affinity of an atom

Tags: electrons, atoms, electron-affinity

I've read that the first electron affinity is always negative, meaning that energy is always released upon the addition of this first electron. However, I don't think this will apply to noble gases. Will adding an electron to a noble gas release energy?

Could someone please clarify electron affinity?

Edit: Even though there are no stable negative ions of noble gases. I assume it is still possible to add an electron. Yet it would require energy. Is this true, meaning the affinity is positive?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_affinity_%28data_page%29  // Note that for historical reasons, Ea is positive when energy is released, the opposite compared to enthalpy change.

Comment: There are no stable negative ions of noble gases. Helium is metastable for long enough to use in accelerators, but that is it.